# accentued character Encoding issue with highcharter in Shiny

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I have a problem with my shiny application.
I display graphics with the package **highcharter** and the letters 'é' are not correctly interpreted (in the title and legend).
In my local environment, I don't have this problem. When I display a graphic with ggplot, I don't have this problem neither (the second graphic in the picture).
Do someone have an idea???

Thank you in advance !

[image: Fail accentued letters]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. To draw the first graph, I used a function stored in a separate file that I imported. All you had to do was add :

source(script_function,**encoding = "UTF-8"**)